# Run a function on page load using SmartClient

Tags: smartclient

When the page loads, I want to hide some buttons based on user permissions.

I have a function that does what I need, but currently I have to press a button to call it.

How to run a `applyUserPermissions` function right after page loads using SmartClient?

```
function applyUserPermissions(){
    btn.setDisabled(false);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same as in plain Javascript

> The statements are executed, one by one, in the same order as they are written.
>
> ~ [w3c Javascript School](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_statements.asp)

So like this:

```
<script>

function applyUserPermissions(){
    btn.setDisabled(false);
}

// calls it on page load
applyUserPermissions();

</script>
```